# /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/pkg name using getContentResolver() query In android

Tags: android

I want to get Folder data from /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/pkg name/folder name

```
            cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
            new String[]{"%" + mBaseFolderPath + "%"},
            orderBy + " DESC");
```

but not getting data please any body help. I will thankful.

Comment: What kind of folder data are you after?

Comment: That looks like an apps specific path. The mediastore has no info about such app specific folders.

Comment: simple as if i create folder in my Android/data/packageName it creates and i also copy videos in it programmatically its works fine but the issue is not getting that videos.

Comment: as you give answer in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60024543/android-q-how-to-get-a-list-of-images-from-a-specific-directory/60024899#60024899. Your right if your path is String path = "MyMedia/Photo"; If Your path is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc.com/MyMedia/Photo then how will you get photos.

Comment: `new File(path).listFiles();`

Comment: yes i know this way but i want to do it by using  Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(){}

Comment: That will not go with the path you used as that parth is an app specific path and i already told you that the media store has no info about such paths.

Comment: ok thanx for help.